# Where is webview component in eclipse pallet?

Tags: android, eclipse

i am developing an android app and it happened that after working with layouts i needed the webview component from the left pallet pane and couldnt see it anymore under composite. Is it a bug what should i do re install eclispe. I am on mac OS.

Many thanks :)

Comment: Have you scrolled to the bottom? What is your ADT version?

Comment: Hello the adt version is  Version: 20.0.3.v201208082019-427395

Comment: Can tell that it's there in Composite for me (same ADT version, API versions 8 to 16) - http://imgur.com/iZEn8. You can try re-installing the ADT.

Comment: ok thanks Rajesh i will try to reinstall ADT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is under the Composite tab of the Palette. You could also just type `<WebView />` in the XML.

If you compile with `<WebView />` and it works, then its probably an eclipse bug. If it throws an exception or something then its probably a setting in your app.

I have worked a lot with the WebView as of late, it is a great feature and I recommend using HTML5 App Cache and localStorage. Makes for a very responsive app. Also use ontouchstart events in the javascript, increases the responsiveness dramatically.

Comment: Hello thanks for your response i will use the webview in xml by typing . HTMl 5 apps you are telling me a complete app using frameworks like phonegap?

Comment: HTML5 is the new 'version' if you will, of HTML. Most websites conform to HTML 4.01. Its simply a bunch of new elements to use in your website. Most noteworthy are the Canvas, Audio and Video tags. I personally have made use of the localStorage. It's like cookies, except better :)